# Can you interactively modify the terminal reset in 'less'?

Tags: less, terminfo, termcap

I usually do not want to reset the terminal when I exit `less` (that is, I want the screen to continue displaying what I was looking at).  Usually, when I'm on a new box and haven't configured it yet, I invoke `less`, quit, see the screen reset, curse mildly, and rerun with `less -X ...`  On very rare occasions, I remember that the screen is going to reset as soon as I quit, in which case the sequence of events is slightly modified and the mild cursing occurs before I quit, but the overall effect is about the same.

Is there any way to modify a currently running `less` process so that it will not reset the terminal upon exit?

Comment: short - no.  long - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Some terminals (such as xterm) have a menu setting which enable/disables switching to/from alternate screen.  Most do not...

By the way (same issue of some/most), if a terminal implements the original xterm  **`47`** code alternate-screen switching, it is possible to switch back into the alternate screen without clearing it.  I've noticed some which set `TERM=xterm` which do not implement this (only implementing the later **`1049`** code) - *ymmv*

You can see how the **`47`** code is used in a normal terminal description by looking at the *`smcup`* and *`rmcup`* capabilities from

```
infocmp xterm-old
```

which shows these items (among others):

```
rmcup=\E[2J\E[?47l\E8,
smcup=\E7\E[?47h,
```

The **`\E[2J`** in *`rmcup`* clears the (alternate) screen before switching back to the normal screen.  The **`\E7`** and **`\E8`** save/restore the cursor position (for the normal screen).  If you really *wanted* to, you could replace those capabilities with whatever ***xterm***-compatible terminal description, omitting the clear-screen part, allowing you to do

```
tput smcup
tput rmcup
```

from the command-line and see what was on the alternate screen.  It wouldn't be nice (since your command-line would overwrite parts of it), but it might help.

It's not needed in xterm, since xterm has a menu option for switching back/forth.  But you might find that approach useful.

Further reading:

- [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite) (xterm FAQ)
- [XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)

Answer (score 3):

use `| . cat`.

Stepwise: press `|`, then at the `|mark:` prompt press `.`, then at the `!` prompt enter `cat`, then at the `|done  (press RETURN)` prompt press Enter again; when you quit `less`, the current page we be left on the screen.

If you want the output to be processed as it was by `less` (with backspace+underscore transformed to underline, non-printable characters shown as `<XX>`, etc), use `less -FX` instead of `cat`.

from the `less(1)` manpage:

> ```
>   | <m> shell-command
>           <m> represents any mark letter.  Pipes a section  of  the  input
>           file  to the given shell command.  The section of the file to be
>           piped is between the first line on the current  screen  and  the
>           position  marked by the letter.  <m> may also be ^ or $ to indi-
>           cate beginning or end of file respectively.  If <m> is . or new-
>           line, the current screen is piped.
> ```

Afterwards, if you want to simply zap the `rmcup`/`smcup` alternate screen switching without having to reconfigure again and again every xterm clone, you can use this command:

```
infocmp | sed 's/[sr]mcup=[^=]*,//g' | tic -
```

This will write inside `~/.terminfo` a terminal description for your current terminal with the codes for alternate screen switching omitted. It should be used in preference to that from `/usr/share/terminfo` by most programs.

Comment: That prints the file which less is rendering, but it's not the same, e.g., if it contains non-printing characters (and does not affect the reset).

Comment: @ThomasDickey  I hope I addressed your objections in the last revision.

Comment: That's better (writing an approximation to the normal screen), though as noted, you can't modify the reset from within less :-)

Comment: This is ingenious.  To make sure I understand what's happening,  less writes to the alternate screen and the shell out to cat writes to the normal screen?

Comment: @WilliamPursell exactly.